# Move and resize XMonad window - RationalRect call compiler error

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors, xmonad

to send the focused window to the center of the screen I have the following configuration

```
main = do
xmonad $ docks def
  { manageHook = myManageHook <+> manageHook def
  , layoutHook = avoidStruts  $  layoutHook def
  , logHook = dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP
  , terminal    = myTerminal
  } `additionalKeys`
  [ ((myModkey , xK_space), spawn myTerminal )
  , ((myModkey , xK_0), withFocused (keysMoveWindowTo (512,384) (0, 0)))
  ]
```

I would remove the call to *keysMoveWindowTo* because it does not allow to set the window size ([...](https://xmonad.github.io/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Actions-FloatKeys.html)) but only specify *dx* and *dy*;  than I would like to use:

`((myModkey , xK_0), withFocused (doRectFloat (RationalRect (1 % 4) (1 % 4) (1 % 2) (1 % 2))))`

but the compiler says:

```
xmonad.hs:87:58: error:
  Data constructor not in scope:
    RationalRect
      :: Ratio a0
    87 |, ((myModkey , xK_0), withFocused (doRectFloat (RationalRect (1 % 4) (1 % 4) (1 % 2) (1 % 2))))
```

What is the correct way to bind keys with *doRectFloat* function?

Thanks

Nello

Answer (score 0):

`doRectFloat` [does not provide](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.1/docs/src/XMonad.Hooks.ManageHelpers.html#doRectFloat) an X operation needed by `withFocused`.

Enhancing your previous solution, you could add `keysResizeWindow` to do the resizing, e.g.

```hs
, ((myModkey , xK_0), withFocused (
    keysMoveWindowTo (512,384) (1%2, 1%2) >> keysResizeWindow (512, 384) (1%2, 1%2)
  ))
```

Comment: I think this increases the width by 512 rather than setting the width to 512 (similary for height and 384).

Comment: @DanielWagner Of course, the `FloatKeys` actions are designed to successively resize (and move) floating windows (by keystroke), hence they can only shrink and enlarge by dx/dy. The actual values were examples (taken from the OP's sample, which I believe were also just dummies), and would have to be calculated elsewhere based on OP's actual screen geometries. To set absolute values, manipulating the `StackSet` directly could be an alternative.

Comment: It does not compile due to `Variable not in scope: (%) :: t6 -> t7 -> Rational`

Comment: @Nellinux Can you be more precise regarding the error message? Have you imported the necessary modules? That is, `keysMoveWindowTo` and `keysResizeWindow` are defined in `XMonad.Actions.FloatKeys`.